# Laravel 5 - Pass More Perminssion in controller

Tags: laravel

I installed laravel 5 alexpechkarev package. I created permission,role and users.
This is what they gave for permission allowed method
 **$permissions = ['role'=>['Admin', 'Staff']  ];**
But Admin only have access i can't access page with Staff User.. How can i do this 
Thanks in Advance

This is my controller code..

```
public function __construct() 
{ 
 $permissions = ['role'=>['Admin', 'Staff'] ]; 
if( is_object(Request::route()) ) 
{
Request::route()->setParameter('larbac', $permissions); 
$this->middleware('larbac'); 
}
}
```

Here Admin can Access all those things like view, edit, delete but Staff can't view, edit, delete the page

Comment: please improve your question so that we understand better. You can add more codes example for a clearer question. Show us what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry.. This is my controller code..

public function __construct() {
        
      $permissions = ['role'=>['Admin', 'Staff']  ];
      if( is_object(Request::route()) ) {

          Request::route()->setParameter('larbac', $permissions);
          $this->middleware('larbac');  
      }         
        
}

Here Admin can Access all those things like view, edit, delete but Staff can't view, edit, delete the page

Comment: edit your question to include the controller code. not in comment

Comment: I can see you are using this package https://github.com/alexpechkarev/larbac , however the thing is your question is specific to this package and not everyone knows about this particular package, so getting an answer for this question is slim